# Jquery no such interface supported

Tags: jquery, css, html

```
var $html = $(status.content).css({opacity: 0});
$html.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $('#' + feed.settings.feedArea).append($html);
    $html.animate({ opacity: 1 });
    $('#' + feed.settings.feedArea).masonry( 'appended', $html, false );
});
```

`status.content` is an html response received from server. This is essentially within an ajax `callback` function. In IE apparently, its complaining that no such interface exist in `jquery.js`, `line 2 character 74347` - its pointing to a `getComputerStyle` function (`jquery 1.8`). In chrome and any other browsers, it works... Even in an Ipad and Iphone... I did a bit of debugging and apparently commenting out the animate solves the problem. So the problem is that IE doesn't support animate opacity?

Comment: I guess it should be `getComputedStyle()`. `:)` And can you be a bit clear in the message?

Comment: Please post some more code as like the Ajax Function calls and if possible, create a Fiddle !

Comment: For me, when I wanted to change the [opacity of an object in CSS for IE](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/), I have to use something like, filter: alpha(opacity=100); So maybe you could add an if statement for ie, and then animate on the filter property.

Comment: Did you check this to avoid that getComputedStyle error in IE? - http://snipplr.com/view/13523/

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a solution to your problem, but I hope it could help others that see this error.

I saw this error when I was (mistakenly) trying to create a jquery object from with two root elements.

```
$('<div>...</div><div>...</div>').appendTo($content).slideDown();
```

Calling slideDown (or any animation function) caused this problem in IE (10).

I did not see this exception in chrome (but I did eventually see other problems).

I always intended there to be a single root div element, and adding that solved my problem.